# Updating Terminal Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, python

Currently on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I am running Python 2.7.6. Is there any way to update this version to Python 3.4.3 (or even more recent than that)?

Comment: Your 14.04 system should already have python 3.4.0, however it will need to be invoked as `python3` rather than `python`. **DO NOT** attempt to upgrade your python 2.7.6 to version 3.x, as it will almost certainly break your system.

Comment: So when I type `python -V` why do I see 2.7.6? Shouldn't I see 3.4.0?

Comment: No, you would need to type `python3 -V`

Comment: @steeldriver can you move it to an answer please.